# Ler um número começando com 0

Tags: c, scanf

Estou a ter uns problemas a ler um numero inicializado com `long long`

```
long long valid;
scanf("%lli", &valid);
```

Input:

`025`

A variável `valid` vai ter como conteúdo `21` e não `25`

Se eu mudar de `%lli` para `%llu` isso já corrige o problema, mas não percebo o porquê, aliás, ao usar `%llu` deveria de ser para `unsigned long long` e não para `long long`.

- Como corrigir isso? Terei obrigatoriamente de mudar para `%llu` ?
- Porque acontece isso quando escrevemos um numero começando com `0`?

[**Código no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/eT37hH)

Comment: Quando começa com `0`, o restante dos dígitos são tratados como um número na base 8: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2xf226.aspx - e `25` na base 8 é igual a `21` na base 10. Agora porque funciona quando muda para unsigned, isso eu não lembro (preciso voltar a mexer com C...)

Comment: @hkotsubo Quando mudamos para unsigned provavelmente o numero é tratado como decimal. Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quiser ignorar o zero deve ler de forma obrigatoriamente decimal, e isto se dá usado o `%d`, e por ser um `long long` de ser `%lld`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long valid;
    scanf("%lld", &valid);
    printf("%lld", valid);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LTUm09). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yyaqfefa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/LongLong.c).

O `%lli` diz que quer um número, não importa a notação digitada, e quando começa com zero ele entende que é octal. Em quase todos os casos o `%i` é erro.

Mas se quer o `0` mesmo antes mesmo aí é diferente.

Vou repetir mais um vez, número é número. Então a matemática define que zero à esquerda não tem significado, por isso ele é ignorado.

Se deseja ler um zero à esquerda de forma significativa não está querendo ler um número, está querendo ler um texto que possui dígitos numéricos. São conceitos completamente diferentes. Se deseja isto mesmo, então mande ler um `char *` com `%s`, aí pode por `0` onde quiser.

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Pois, realmente ja tinha lido sobre o `%i` e `%d`, porem pensei que era obrigatório usar o `%lli` para ler um `long long`